# JS Convert string into multi dimensional object keys

Tags: javascript

I have a string, for example:

```
convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose
```

that I want to create a object key 'nose' (tank object is already created) :

```
tank['convert']['lamp']['stamp']['glass']['nose']
```

How would I do that?

I got array using split

```
values = 'convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose'.split('.');
```

now i am not sure how to use jquery's each method to create those keys.

Comment: With 74 REP (which will soon be much less unless you change your question) you should know HOW to ask.  Please post code and effort

Comment: Hello, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: It is still not a good question. Please show your efforts. You need split or map

Comment: `var newstr = 'tank["'+str.split(".").join('"]["')+'"]';`

Comment: I want object, not a string.

Comment: Not recommended but `var obj = eval('tank["'+str.split(".").join('"]["')+'"]')`

Comment: do you want to create an object with the keys?

Comment: Hello Nina, yes i want an object.

Comment: What you are doing is a bad practice I think. Why can't you use an array instead of a string representation of this path?

Comment: I get that string from the css id/class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string and use it as the keys for an object.

This proposal uses

- [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- and a default value `v || {}` if an object does not exist.

```js
var object = { convert: { lamp: { stamp: { glass: { nose: 42 } } } } },
    path = 'convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose',
    value = path.split('.').reduce(function (v, k) {
        return (v || {})[k];
    }, object);

console.log(value);
```

ES6

```js
var object = { convert: { lamp: { stamp: { glass: { nose: 42 } } } } },
    path = 'convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose',
    value = path.split('.').reduce((v, k) => (v || {})[k], object);

console.log(value);
```

For creating an object, with the given keys, you could use this

```js
var object = {},
    path = 'convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose'.split('.'),
    last = path.pop();

path.reduce(function (o, k) {
    o[k] = o[k] || {};
    return o[k];
}, object)[last] = 42;

console.log(object);
```

ES6

```js
var object = {},
    path = 'convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose'.split('.'),
    last = path.pop();

path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = 42;
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows, however you should also provide a value for the last property which is `nose` here. I had done an Object.prototype method for this called `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` which will allow you to do this job dynamically. It will take an array of strings or integers which will be used as nested properties and the last item in the array will be used as the value. If the array item is integer it will generate an array object instead.

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var tank = {};
   props = "convert.lamp.stamp.glass.nose".split(".");
props.push(100) // lets assign a value to the nose property
tank.setNestedValue(...props);
console.log(JSON.stringify(tank,null,2));
```